Version error in Xcode despite adding Xcode's suggested check
Xcode 15.4 - I am modifying my drawing app to use the new hover functionality supported by the new Apple Pencil. I get the following error, which disappears shortly after it is shown.
Note the method is tagged with @available, which should squelch the error, which I guess is why it disappears after a moment. But the build is not happening. I figure this is an Xcode bug, but is there a workaround?


Hmm - it seems Xcode's solution was fixing an application extension rather than iOS. Changing iOSApplicationExtension to simply iOS fixed the issue, but I may have to check the extension as well.
